# Whoops, looks like something went wrong, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I   get free host from 000webhost.com and  it was working fine,  but after two weeks  i get the error 
"Whoops, looks like something went wrong".
I use laravel framework  for php.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your question is not thorough enough. You should, at least, provide us with your server logs(apache logs) and laravel logs.

Also do you have this error on all pages?

Comment: you have 500 error, check your log file `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the solution :

- First i go to app.php and change the value of APP_DEBUG = true
- I get the error name " No application key generated "
- I run code `php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score 6):

First of all, in `config/app.php` set debug to `true` or in your .env file set `APP_DEBUG=true`. This should turn on the debugging errors **On** on your server. If errors are still not visible, try `php artisan config:clear` for making changes to take effect. You may also check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for errors.

Possible problems are:

- Your server's configurations does not meet the [Laravel's requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#server-requirements).
- Laravel does not have read/write access to `bootstrap/cache` folder.
- Project dependencies not installed or not supported.

Comment: Or he has a typo somewhere, or a billion other ways a 500 gets thrown.

Comment: @ggdx Indeed. Unless we know, what the error is thrown :P